# jqPlot adding 0 value

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm using the jqPlot library to build charts. I'm using some JS to fetch a JSON file, build a string using values from the JSON file, convert it to a nested array (the only format that jqPlot likes) and then passing to jqplot. jqPlot is reading the arry just fine and is plotting the correct values, but its adding a 0 value at the end.

Here's the string code:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("test.json", chartData);
    function chartData(data) {
                $.each(data.values, function(index,val){ 
                    chartValues += val + ",";
                });
            };
```

here's the code that converts it into a nested array:

```
var temp = new Array();
temp = chartValues.split(',');
var temp2 = new Array(temp);
alert(temp2);
```

So when temp2 is passed to jqplot it adds a zero, but when I pass it an identical nested array called test that is declared manually, it doesn't add the zero. Here they are for comparison:

```
var test = [[12,32,21,23,34,43,52,86,25,]];
```

and here's temp2

```
[[12,32,21,23,34,43,52,86,25,]]
```

Any ideas? I'd also appreciate any help with my logic in this, as I feel like I could be creating the nested array more elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the last character in the string (before converting to an array) was the solution in this case.

```
newStr = chartValues.substring(0, chartValues.length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 100% at this point but I think in .....86,25,]] is not right. That might be the reason to add a zero value. Try eliminating this. Another thing is that you can access the data arrays in json files directly using basic access methods. Try at json org.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized that even though it wasn't displaying the final zero value, new array was adding a 0 value after the last "," - a simple line of code (below) fixed the issue